# C# Double dictionary change value

Tags: c#, dictionary

Hello I have the following dictionary and can add and read from it but not change the value.

```
    class GamesPlayersClass
    {
        public string nickname { get; set; }
        public int status { get; set; } //0 not ready 1 ready 2 finished
        public int dies { get; set; }
        public int score { get; set; }
        public int totaltime { get; set; }
    }

    static Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, GamesPlayersClass>> gamesplayers = new Dictionary<int, Dictionary<int, GamesPlayersClass>>();
```

Adding an entry to the dictionary :

```
       Dictionary<int, GamesPlayersClass> playerinfo = new Dictionary<int, GamesPlayersClass>();
       playerinfo.Add(games.Count,
       new GamesPlayersClass
       {
                        nickname = nickName,
                        status = 0,
                        dies = 0,
                        score = 0,
                        totaltime = 0
        });
        gamesplayers.Add(games.Count, playerinfo);
```

Any idea how I could for example change the following value ?
gamesplayers[0]dictionary2[0].Value.status = 1;

I hope I asked my question clear as Im new to Stackoverflow. Thanks for helping.

[EDIT] I know I can check if the key exist but not how to change it for key exist i try

```
if (gamesplayers[0].ContainsKey(0));
```

[EDIT2] Beside this any idea how I can quickly check if the second dictonary has a certain value

```
foreach (var game in gamesplayers )
{
foreach (var playerinfo in game)
{
  if (playerinfo.Value.nickname == nickName)
{
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the keys exist, you can access a dictionary value by its indexer (`Dictionary[key]` notation). Since you have a nested dictionary, you can call both the indexers

```
gamesplayers[0][0].status = 1;
```

---

**Note 1** : this is not thread safe

**Note 2** : you should probably use [`TryGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2.trygetvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) and add the appropriate fault tolerance

**Update**

Your edited code is fine, just use `Contains`, however you'll find `TryGetValue` more convenient in most situations. If you wanted to get fancy you could write your own *Extension Method*

```
public static class Extensions
{
   // checks if both keys exists and returns true or false
   // returns a result if valid
   public static bool TryGetValue<TKey1, TKey2, TValue>(this Dictionary<TKey1, Dictionary<TKey2, TValue>> dict, TKey1 key1, TKey2 key2, out TValue result)
   {
      if(dict == null)
         throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dict));

      result = default;

      return dict.TryGetValue(key1, out var nestedDict) && nestedDict.TryGetValue(key2, out result);
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
If(gamesplayers.TryGetValue(key1, key2, out var result))
  Debug.WriteLine($"yay we checked and returned a result {result.nickname}");
```

**Note 3** : this is for academic purposes only, and may not be the best solution to what you actually want. However it does show you how to use `TryGetValue`

Comment: Hmm Im sure I tried that but I must have done something wrong. Sometimes it's very easy ! Thanks.

Comment: Do you mind answering this a side question, I added it in the edit of my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
foreach (var outer in gamesplayers)
{
    foreach (var inner in outer.Value)
    {
        if(inner.Key == "Something")
        {
            // do something
            inner.Value = “test”;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but will this also change the value of the dictionary in gamesplayers or only set it for the new var inner ?

Comment: @Jefke22 most objects in C# are passed by reference, not by value. So if you update something in a for/each loop then it will (usually) update the value it was referencing, so not just `inner` but `gamesplayers` too - as `inner` is a reference to a particular entry in `gamesplayers`

Comment: Besides using [0].[0] is very buggy..using dictionary containskey and changing the value by key is recomennded

Comment: Thanks guys I think I pretty much understand it. BUT besides the double foreach of Gauravsa there is no faster and less resource using way ? This just dont feel right to loop over anything for my feeling.

Comment: Ok.. if it helps please click on tick and make it green :).. also please combine this with TryGetValue..

Answer (score 0):

You can use LINQ

```
var gKey = 1;
var pKey = 1;
var game = (from g in gamesplayers where g.key == gKey).FirstOrDefault();
var playerinfo = (from p in game where p.key == pKey).FirstOrDefault();
playerinfo[pKey].Value.status =  "status";
```

Answer (score 0):

Struggling to understand why you need the second Dictionary, due to being able to just put the count against the game already. You also may want to look into using Lists of the class with a unique identifier on the class due to Dictionary's being inherently difficult to understand the deeper they get. However to fix your problem would recommend using linq as below

```
gameplayers.Where(gp => gp.Key == "insertExpectedIntHere" && 
                    gp.Any(p => p.Key == "insertExpectedIntHere" && p.nickname == "nicknameHere");

if (gameplayers != null)
{
    Do the thing
}
else
{
    Do the other thing
}
```

I believe this would work for you. But dictionary's are confusing so might require a bit of moving around (Again recommend trading out for unique identifiable list classes. Can provide example if needed)

Comment: Because the program will offer multiples games thats why a double dictionary.

Comment: But the same effect can be done with lists, and it be easier to search for values and easier to understand in most situations.